# Salesforce to Salesforce - Pending(sent) External Sharing Status

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

I have programmatic record forwarding for a Salesforce to Salesforce integration. For unknown reasons 1 out of every 4000ish records get stuck with the pending(sent) external sharing status and never make it over to the other org.

[image]

The receiving org has no validation rules, required fields, apex, etc. that would block the record insertion. This is just record insertion into a vanilla custom object with 40 fields.

No records appear for me to even manually accept in the receiving org, the records just disappear. What gives? The connection history shows no failures.

Any one encountered similiar issues with their Salesforce to Salesforce integration?

UPDATE:

After about 48-72 hours it eventually marked the connection as inactive despite the connection being active and actively fowarding and updating other records between the two orgs. Any one encounter this before?

[image]